# Ubuntu 13.04 will not connect to share network drive

Tags: networking, 13.04, samba

I have an Ubuntu PC used as a file server running 12.10 64bit. I am able to connect to it using Linux Mint, Windows7 and Windows 8, but unable to connect using Ubuntu 13.04.

I have tried creating a link on the 13.04 Desktop, but the 'create launcher' feature has been removed from the right click menu, so tried via terminal to create the link:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

however, clicking on the launcher just times out.

Tried to connect through Dolphin, the same problem, connection times out.

If I explore the local network going to location `smb:///` the connection times out.

If I try to go direct to a share folder `smb://192.168.0.2/Videos` again times out

Comment: Have the same problem as you.. I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my HTPC and have set-up a share, can access it from anywhere but not my laptop, Ubuntu 12.10. Can connect from win7, win8 and Android.. Why so difficult? Have to use FTP or SSH to transfer files and then move it to the correct folder on the HTPC..

Comment: Can you connect to it with smbclient? Something like `smbclient \\\\zimmerman\\public mypasswd` or with -Uusername if it is shared for a specific username.
You should also install cifs-utils to be able to mount them

Comment: Thanks. I was always able to connect in Nautilus just using either smb:/// and browsing the network or direct to a drive using smb://192.168.0.2/Videos So what has changed I wonder? I can still connect using a Linux Mint laptop, which is based on an earlier version of Ubuntu, I believe 12.04LTS, however Mint is tweaked so only vaguely resembles Ubuntu. I may try a downgrade to Nautilus to 3.4 or the SolusOS Nautilus Patch.... Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this info and it resolved my issue:

**We will need to edit the smb.conf and the nsswitch.conf:**

- add the name of your network example: MSHOME or WORKGROUP ,etc
- we will add your computer name, in my case: pst007x-Serval-Professional
- change name resolve order
- edit the HOSTS in the nsswitch.conf

**RUN in Terminal:**

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

**EDIT THE smb.conf FILE, add the *workgroup* and *netbios name*:**

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ##

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of

workgroup = WORKGROUP

netbios name = pst007x-Serval-Professional

**NOW FIND:**

;        name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast

**CHANGE THIS LINE TO:**

name resolve order = lmhosts wins bcast host

**SAVE AND EXIT**

**NOW ONE MORE FILE TO EDIT:**

```
sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

**CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINE:**

hosts:          files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4

**TO:**

hosts:          files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] wins dns mdns4

**NOW RESTART SYSTEM**